# Problema con Google Maps: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android

estoy practicando con el ejemplo de un videoturorial, he revisado el codigo varias veces, pero la aplicación no llega a funcionar, en el videotutorial si se ve que funciona, pero cuando voy a mostrar el mapa la aplicación se cierra.

Intento ver el funcionamiento de este código para ver si luego puedo cambiarlo para poner el mapa que tengo creado en un archivo HTML.

este es codigo que tengo puesto:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button ubicarme;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ubicarme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ubicarme);

        ubicarme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        int status= GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (status== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }else {
            Dialog dialog=GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,(Activity) getApplicationContext(),10);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        UiSettings uiSettings=mMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Hola").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        float zoomlevel=16;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,zoomlevel)); 
    }
}
```

No si si tengo que poner algun dato mas para que podais ver por donde falla la aplicación.

Error que muestra

```
12/29 18:41:50: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\SoCu\AndroidStudioProjects\googlemaps\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps/com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 3642 on device Nexus_5X_API_27_x86 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
E/zygote: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active

          [ 12-29 17:42:05.477  1597: 1644 D/         ]
          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x92b27040, tid 1644
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xab005120: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab005120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xab003290)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab005120: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xab003290)
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11910000 but found 11580470
I/chatty: uid=10090(com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps) identical 8 lines
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 11910000 but found 11580470
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps, PID: 3642
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps/com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                      at com.example.codigofacilito.googlemaps.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:35)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Amigo SoCu, recuerda que en Android decir "la app se cierra", se puede deber a infinidad de causas, revisa en el LogCat que mensaje de error se muestra!:)

Comment: Hola Jorgesys he visto en en el código que he pegado del **MapsActivity.java** no han salido unas lineas tachadas, no se si puede ser ese el problema, no le he dado mucha importancia porque en el tutorial también se muestran http://funkyimg.com/i/2AJdD.png como no puedo poner mucho texto y encima sale todo sin salto de linea pongo una imagen del trozo donde creo que se muestra el error http://funkyimg.com/i/2AJdD.png que es justo al pulsar el boton para que muestre el menu

Comment: Los métodos que indicas son obsoletos pero pueden funcionar, te indico nuevamente agregar el mensaje de error registrado en el LogCat para saber exactamente cual es el problema.

Comment: perdón puse dos veces la misma imagen, la segunda imagen era una captura del error que muestra, a ver si he acertado ahora http://funkyimg.com/i/2AJRQ.png si no es esto lo del mensaje dime como puedo sacarlo, voy a ponerla en el primer post para que se vea mejor

Comment: Coloca el logcat como texto no como imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se genera en esta linea:

```
Dialog dialog=GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,(Activity) getApplicationContext(),10);
```

y es causado porque estas tratando de castear el contexto como Activity, esta definido como:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to android.app.Activity

`Application` no es subclase de `Activity`, por lo tanto si estas dentro de una activity puedes obtener el contexto de la misma de esta forma usando `this` :

```
Dialog dialog=GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,this,10);
```

Comment: ahora parece que si, pero se queda bloqueado, creo que el emulador, no sabria decirte, cuando pulso el boton para que muestre el mapa, muestra un mensaje en la pantalla del emulador para actualizar Google Play services, pulso el boton UPDATE, muestra un texto que dice "googlemaps won´t run unless you update Google Play services. pero no pasa de ahi. como se actualiza si el boton de update no hace nada.

Comment: vale, ya estoy actualizando, he cambiado de telefono en el emulador

Comment: @SoCu ok, tienes que actualizar Google Play Services en tu emulador.

Comment: Ok, ya lo tengo muchas gracias, este problema si se ha solucionado, creo que ahora viene otro mas gordo, jeje, ahora voy a ver si puedo poner una pagina web donde tengo creado un navegador, bueno un menu con coordenadas para ponerlas en el navegador